# When using MongoDB with TypeScript, should I add an _id field to the interfaces of my models?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

This is the fist time I use MongoDB with Mongoose and Typescript. I am defining an interface for each model of my database.

Should I add the `_id` field to the interfaces I create, like I am doing in this code snippet?

```js
import mongoose, { Model, Document, ObjectId } from "mongoose";
export interface IUser extends Document {
  _id: ObjectId;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  created: Date;
  isPremium: boolean;
  img?: string;
  applicantProfile?: string;
  businessProfile?: string;
}

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  email: { type: String, required: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
  isPremium: { type: Boolean, required: true, default: true },
  created: { type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now },
  img: String,
  applicantProfile: String,
  businessProfile: String,
});

export const User: Model<IUser> = mongoose.model("User", userSchema)
```

The tutorials I have read about Mongo + Typescript don't do this, but I have found that, if I don't declare the `_id` field in my interface, then, when I try to access the _id field, it has a value of `any`, which I don't like.

I'd like to know how you create the interfaces of your models and whether adding the _id field to the interface is a good practice.

Comment: I personally do add `_id`, I don't see why not.

Comment: This link has some useful information on declaring _id in Typescript interfaces for Mongo Collections:  https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/typescript/#working-with-the-_id-field